# File has unexpected size

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An error occurred when I installed ros，Here's what I do：

```
$ sudo sh -c '. /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/ $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116

$ sudo apt update
```

Then report an error. May I ask who knows the reason？Is it the ros mirror source that is wrong？

```
Get:3 http://220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [481 kB]
Err:3 http://220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (1343916 != 480706). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 220.112.193.195 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:480706 [weak]
   - SHA256:a3b8443a822d1005b5a4577ede042691e4600e6597de0e76004b84678688481b
   - SHA1:d9aabcc8dcda723e7bde45f8bacbc765865edeb5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4f2fd4debc4d8381ac97f972a79c7286 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 17 May 2019 19:32:55 +0000
```

---

Edit: Thank you for your reply.
I tried to update the ros mirror source on May 28, May 29, and May 30. And i have tried using the following three mirror sources:

1. packages.ros.org
2. mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
3. mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn

But it's all the same mistake.I even installed a new ubuntu system to try.

I used the system: ubuntu18.04

It's hard to believe that all three mirror sources are having problems at the same time,So are there any other possible causes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324307/file-has-unexpected-size/) by [jimy](https://answers.ros.org/users/41918/jimy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
As it is, this does not appear to be a ROS related problem. If you cannot solve it, I would suggest to post on a forum such as Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

> I tried to update the ros mirror source on May 28, May 29, and May 30.

The problem is **not** the ROS mirrors.

The repository at `220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu` is the problem.

Perhaps a `grep 'mirrors.cqu.edu.cn' -r /etc/apt` could help.

---

Original:

> Is it the ros mirror source that is wrong？

The problem does not appear to be the ROS mirror (ie: USTC), but the package repository which is located at:

> ```
> Get:3 http://220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [481 kB]
> ```

```
Err:3 http://220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Notice how the error message mentions `220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu`, which is not the USTC ROS mirror.

I'm not sure what `220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE` is exactly, you should probably know. Is that the mirror you use for Ubuntu Bionic itself?

If this problem persists (ie: even after retrying a few times, for instance tomorrow), you should contact the administrator of the Ubuntu mirror and ask them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimy](https://answers.ros.org/users/41918/jimy/) on 2019-05-30**:
Thank you for your help.
I went to check the website of “220.112.193.195/files/1116000006474FFE/mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/ubuntu”
“220.112.193.195” this IP is not a mirror IP，Then I looked up the location of the IP, which was very close to my company, and I thought it might be a problem with the company network, maybe some wrong domain name mapping or something.

Finally I switched to my phone's Internet connection, and I've solved the problem。

Your advice is very helpful. Thank you very much。